# iOS Firebase Swift, using on OnDisconnect to monitor online status does not work

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would like to monitor the online status of users in Firebase (i.e., to keep a log of who exactly is online), and of course I would like to this online status to react/update as soon as a user logs out or gets disconnected.

I am using this code towards the end of my ViewDidLoad and this seems to work fine for printing online/offline exactly when desired (i.e., connection is lost or user logs out, both of wich I tested).

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener() { auth, user in
if user != nil {
   print("ONLINE")
   databaseRef.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("OnlineStatus").setValue("ON")
 } else { 
   print("OFFLINE")
 }
}
```

Of course, where this prints 'offline', it is too late to change the entry of OnlineStatus since the connection has already been lost. To correct for this, I put this additional line below the above:

```
databaseRef.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("OnlineStatus").onDisconnectSetValue("OFF")
```

My understanding was that this would do specifically what I desire, namely change the desired value to 'OFF' as soon as the connection is lost/disrupted. But this OnDisconnect seems to have no effect whatsoever, and I am confused what I am misunderstanding?

--

Following Jay's answer, I am now using this code (which is taken from Firebase documentation), but it still won't work. Any ideas?

```
let myConnectionsRef = databaseRef.child("users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("OnlineStatus")

let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: ".info/connected")

    connectedRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

        guard let connected = snapshot.value as? Bool, connected else {
            return
        }

        let con = myConnectionsRef
        con.setValue("YES")

        // when this device disconnects, remove it
        // con.onDisconnectRemoveValue()
        con.onDisconnectSetValue("OFF")

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnDisconnect tells the *server* to take an action when the client disconnects. One use case would be an online chat system

Users can see other users, select them and have a chat. Imagine a structure

```
connected_status
  uid_0: true
  uid_1: true
  uid_2: false
```

All clients observe the connected_status node and when a users status changes, their UI is updated - in this case uid_2 has disconnected so their node is set to false. This is done by

```
child("connected_status).child(myUid).onDisconnectSetValue(false)
```

This function is independent of you app knowing if it's connected or not - it a function just for the server.

To monitor your apps connected status, observe a special node in Firebase

```
".info/connected"
```

observing this node will let your App know when it's connected status changes.

We use it in a KVO fashion in that when then the .info/connected changes, we update an 'isConnected' singleton app variable.

In many of our views, we have a class ConnectedImage which is an image that's green when connected and red when disconnected. That class KVO's the singleton isConnected variable and updates it's color whenever it's status changes from false to true, true to false. This lets the user know when the are connected or not.

For completeness, check out the Firebase documentation [Offline Capabilities](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) and scroll down the Detecting Connection State area.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, and I think I generally understand what you are saying -- but I still cannot get it to work (please see additional detail added to my question above) even though (I think) I am using code as stated in Firebase documentation.

Comment: @AJGronevelt Can you be specific? What isn't working? Keep in mind there are two parts to my answer. 1) What the server does when a client disconnects and 2) What the client app does when the client disconnects. For the server side, the design pattern is to have a connected_users node as in my example and all clients observe it. In your client app you have to code like I posted in my answer, which sets the uid_x: to false when it disconnects. Other users are observing that node and will be notified when something in the node changes and can update their UI.

Comment: Thank you for your patience with me. I read your answer many times, every time makes more sense -- so I start to understand how it's meant to be, but struggle with actual code. What's not working is that onDisconnect doesn't act, there's just no way I can get it to change connected_status to 'Off' after I close the app, it just won't do it. I added my code to my original question, but also used variations of that, always same problem.

Comment: as an update: it all works fine (connection breaks off, stop client, etc.) as described above except for when I do FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut() which doesn't fire the disconnect ... so I manually added the change of online status in the sign out function, which patches it. Any idea though why FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut() doesn't trigger the OnDisconnect?